# Why did my code get corrupted (turn into spaces)

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycharm, atom-editor, corruption

I booted up my pc ready to work on one of my projects to find two of them completely corrupted and by corrupted I mean it turned into this [Completely and utterly broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1XLc.png)

This first happened when I was using atom
when I try to open it with visual studio it says [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ4W4.png)
I tried opening it by atom,pycharm heck even mu it just shows spaces. just so many spaces (this is also what happens when I click open anyway in visual studio)

I hope you can help I've already lost hope trying to fix it but I'd like to try to recover it

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like the file is borked.  Maybe your hard disk is failing?  If you have a backup, restore from that.  If you don't have a backup, best move is probably to do the project over (and be grateful you learned this lesson about the importance of backups with a relatively small project rather than something like a bitcoin wallet with a million dollars in it).  Also, run a scan on that disk, and possibly replace the disk if the scan utility indicates that it is indeed failing.

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: For a start, don't put pictures of text (like e.g. error message) so that people can (hint!) search for the error when facing similar problems. Also, you don't ask a programming question, you're just complaining about a bug in some software, which brings me to the next point: Check the according bugtrackers or contact the vendor for assistance. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @a_guest here is the file https://www.mediafire.com/file/9ev3fq6is51fjr0/Main_code.py/file

Comment: @Trashboat I agree with Samwise, it seems to be broken.

Comment: @a_guest Yeah I though that too thanks for the help tho :)